# Magento Product Category still showing after deleting

Tags: magento-1.9, php, url-rewrite, category-products, fatal-error

[image]

I got this really annoying issue with Magento. I attempted to load all my items onto the store but had some bugs. In result, I deleted all my items but I am still showing 57 items in the Category Products and in the URL-Rewrites. I have deleted the categories and subcategories. I have cleared the cash and have re-indexed everything, but still nothing. I need help urgently!

In addition, after uploading and deleting everything I am now getting a FATAL ERROR message if I attempt to export the .csv.

> Fatal error: Unsupported operand types in includes/src/Mage_ImportExport_Model_Export_Entity_Product.php on line 875

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Sounds like a database issue where foreign key constraints are messed up and the delete on cascade did not happen to remove product references from all tables that would be normally affected during product deletion. I would personally consider running the database repair tool.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. And how would you clean up the database? Do you know of a link where I could follow some steps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear to me whether you have deleted those Products and categories through Admin Panel or, Database. But, first, try to disable Compilation from `Magento Admin Panel -> System -> Tools -> Compilation -> Disable`
Then, clear your cache and try CSV upload again

Comment: I added the data from the Import function on the front-end and deleted the items in the front end. I am now only able to see the items when I go into "Catalog > Manage Categories > Category Products" and in the URL Re-writes. I am not able to see the actual product in the front-end or back-end. How would I flush the product database from PHPMyAdmin? and what's causing the Fatal Error?

Comment: Rahul, you're the man. Temporarly disabling the compilation and refreshing the cache fixed the fatal error; nonetheless, I am still having the issue with the products not showing.

Comment: `Catalog` -> `Manage Products`, then select products and DELETE!

Comment: Thank you so much Rahul. I was able to clear the cash and now refresh my database. The only issue I am still encountering is that when I upload items they are not visible in Magento. I need to physically go into each item and then it displays in the front-end. Any work around to fix this?

Comment: How you are uploading products into your magento?

Comment: Systems > Import/Export > Dataflow Profiles > and then I select the Export all to get the formatting and then use the import matching everything. I have also used the straight Export and Import function.

Comment: When you're uploading your product, you're using a CSV file, right? Visibility -> Catalog, Search, i.e. Value 4 need to be set always i=for each product, from the database you're exporting products, see if visibility is set there or not.

Comment: Yes. I have done all that but I am still having issues. Images are not uploading and items are not showing up. could I send you my .csv? maybe you can get a better idea by viewing.

Comment: figured it out. Thank you all for the help:)